# Codeigniter Image resize via subdomain url

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i want make dynamic images url, where assets is subdomain

Working route :

```
$route['assets/images/([A-Za-z]+)/(\d+)/(.+)'] = "resize/img/$1/$2/$3";
```

img url : `localhost/assets/images/test/350/item.jpg`

but what i want its :

```
assets.localhost/images/test/350/item.jpg
```

how to make dynamic image resize with subdomain url like that ?

- Resize controler code :

```
public function img($FileDir, $width,$filename)
    {
        if (isset($filename)){
            
            $FileUrl = 'assets/images/'.$FileDir.'/'.$filename;
            
            if(!file_exists($FileUrl)){
                show_404();
            }
            
            $this->load->library('image_lib');
            
            // configure image library
            $config = array(
                'image_library' => 'gd2',
                'source_image' => $FileUrl,
                'create_thumb' => true,
                'maintain_ratio' => true,
                'dynamic_output' => true,
                'quality' => '60%',
                'width' => $width
            );
            
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();
            $this->image_lib->clear();
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not important to make a route for assets.

The correct way of making the assets folder is to put your assets folder inside a public folder in the route directory like this.

```
Project_Folder 
> application
> public/assets/images 
> system
```

Once you did it, the 2nd step is to create a subdomain and assign that subdomain to `public/assets` directory.

And here the 3rd step is to create a helper function.

```
function assets_url($uri = '')
{
    return 'https://assets.yourdomain.com/'.$uri;
}
```

And now replace this line in your code.

```
$FileUrl = assets_url('images/'.$FileDir.'/'.$filename);
```